# Como copiar o texto de um ficheiro de texto para outro

Tags: c#

Eu queria copiar o texto de um ficheiro de texto para outro com o nome diferente e adicionar um - no inicio da linha do ficheiro de texto.

Por exemplo:

Tenho um ficheiro de texto com o seguinte texto "0000192" e ao copiar para outro ficheiro de texto queria que fica-se assim "-0000192".

Mas não se como posso fazer isso .

Eu estou a criar o primeiro ficheiro de texto assim :

```
string devolta = Convert.ToString((bsoItemTrans.Transaction.TotalAmount * 100).ToString("-000000000"));
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\movedir\SUBTOTALE.txt", devolta);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tudo o que você precisa fazer é:

1. Ler todas as linhas do primeiro arquivo e pôr numa coleção de *strings*
2. Criar uma nova coleção onde cada linha é prefixada com **`-`**
3. Salvar esta nova coleção num arquivo

Código:

```
var linhas = File.ReadAllLines("primeiroArquivo.txt"); // Passo 1
linhas = linhas.Select(l => $"-{l}").ToArray();        // Passo 2
File.WriteAllLines("novoArquivo.txt", linhas);         // Passo 3
```

Obviamente ele pode ser transformado em *one-liner*:

```
File.WriteAllLines("a2.txt", File.ReadAllLines("a1.txt").Select(l => $"-{l}").ToArray());
```